# How to load JSONP inside requireJS?

Tags: javascript, callback, requirejs, jsonp, requirejs-define

I'm trying to get a JSONP file to load in requireJS. The [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsonp) say it should work like this:

```
require(["http://example.com/api/data.json?callback=define"],
    function (data) {
        //The data object will be the API response for the
        //JSONP data call.
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

My config.json looks like this (no line breaks):

```
config({
    "default_language":"de-DE",
    "language_current":"de-DE",
    "language_selector":"translate",
    "language_set":"false"
});
```

So my require call should be:

```
require(["http://example.com/api/config.json?config=define"],
    function (data) {
        //The data object will be the API response for the
        //JSONP data call.
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

but doing so only returns `config (the callback function!) is undefined`. I have been sitting over this for a while now... and got it to work like this using the `async` [plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/examples/async.html), but this syntax will not work, because I'm declaring a function outside of a define context.

```
var config = function(data) {
    var settings = {};

  // create application settings
  settings.language_default = data.default_language || "en-EN";
  settings.language_current = data.language_current || priv.settings.language_default;
  settings.language_selector = data.selector || "translate";
  settings.language_set = data.language_set || false;

  console.log(settings);
  // return response object
  return settings;
};

define([
    'async!http://example.com/api/config.json!config'
  ],
  config
);
```

This seems to work, because now I specifically name the callback function `config`.

I guess everything would be ok, if I could pass in `config` as name of my `define-callback` function, but the only way I was able to do it is the above.

**Question**:
How do I correctly load a JSONP file in requireJS either using the default way by requireJS or the loader plugins provider here [https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/examples/async.html]?

This works perfectly fine with a static file loaded from S3:

```
define([],
    function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com/api/configuration.json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "config", /* Unique function name */
            success: function(data){
                /* Do something with data */
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    }
);
```

So why does it not work when being done inside requireJS?

Comment: THat's not JSONP.  You need to write server-side code to handle `callback=`.

Comment: so I cannot just store a hardcoded file with callback({"foo":"bar"});?

Comment: @SLaks: works no problem using `$.ajax` from a static server (see my edit).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one thing:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsonp

You should use like this:

```
require(["http://example.com/api/data.json?callback=define"],
    function (data) {
        //The data object will be the API response for the
        //JSONP data call.
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

The `callback` is the object wrapped in the `jsonp`:

If your `callback` is **define** then use `define`

```
define({
    "default_language":"de-DE",
    "language_current":"de-DE",
    "language_selector":"translate",
    "language_set":"false"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This works.

```
define(["async"],
    function () {
        callback = function(d) {
            console.log("callback called");
             console.log(d);
        };

        require([
            "async!http://www.example.com/api/configuration.json"
        ],
        callback
        );
    }
);
```

Maybe also someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem , had to resort to using `$.ajax()` to load the gapi script. .